# Days between two dates in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I find the number of days between the date of the employee's employment and the date of the day, and multiply by the daily amount. The only complaint is that when I find out the number of days between two dates, it calculates over 31 days for the months that draw 31 days naturally. I need to trade over 30 days while I get the dates between two dates.

How can I do that?

Comment: what about February ? or leap year?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking.  Maybe if you show some examples and what you have tried it would help.

Comment: First Date : 2016-10-03 LastDate : 2016-11-03 (int)(firstDate - lastDate).TotalDays;  result : 31 Days. I want to have 30 days.

Comment: @deadLocked There are 31 days between those two dates, not 30. Your requirements are nonsensical.

Comment: I know it's 31 days. Is there a way to find it in 30 days?

Comment: @deadLocked Yeah there is. `if (datediff >= 31) return 30;`. It's stupid as hell, but it gets what you want.

Comment: My friend does not have a month between dates. These calculation dates may be different.

Comment: @deadLocked then add some additional logic to the if statements to make it slightly less broken. Again, your requirements are nonsensical, so you are going to have to cater for those scenarios yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2016, 10, 3);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2016, 11, 3);
var numberOfDays = date2.Subtract(date1).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this is what you wanted:

```
 DateTime firstDay = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-10-03", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 DateTime lastDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-11-03", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 double daysBetween = (lastDate - firstDay).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are just interested in full month, you can use following code

```
var normalisedDays = ((lastDate.Year - firstDate.Year) * 12 + lastDate.Month - firstDate.Month) * 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

***in Controll :***

```
DateTime Date_1 = Date_Start;
DateTime Date_2 = Date_End;
TimeSpan difference = Date_2  - Date_1 ;
var days = difference.TotalDays;
```

***in Script :***

```
<script>
function calculateDifference()
{
    var Date_Start= document.getElementById("Date_Start").value;
    var Date_End= document.getElementById("Date_End").value;
    var Date_StartSplit = Date_Start.split("/");
    var Date_EndSplit = Date_End.split("/");

    var StartDate = new Date(Date_StartSplit[2], Date_StartSplit[0] - 1, Date_StartSplit[1]);
    var EndDate = new Date(Date_EndSplit[2], Date_EndSplit[0] - 1, Date_EndSplit[1]);
    var res = Math.abs(StartDate - EndDate) / 1000;
    var days = Math.floor(res / 86400);
    document.getElementById("Nombre_days").value = days;

}
</script>
```